# Does += operator ensures an EXPLICIT conversion or implicit CASTING in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, clr

The example below compiles:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Byte b = 255;
    b += 100;

}
```

but this one below fails

```
   public static void Main()
    {
        Byte b = 255;
        b = b + 100;
    }
```

with

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Does this mean that for C# += operator provides EXPLICIT conversion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eric Lippert answered your question [at great length](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx).

> Another interesting aspect of the predefined compound operators is
>   that if necessary, a cast – an allegedly “explicit” conversion – is
>   inserted implicitly on your behalf. If you say
>
> ```
> short s = 123;
> s += 10;
> ```
>
> then that is not analyzed as s = s + 10 because short plus int is int,
>   so the assignment is bad. This is actually analyzed as
>
> ```
> s = (short)(s + 10);
> ```
>
> so that if the result overflows a short, it is automatically cut back
>   down to size for you.

See also [part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/01/compound-assignment-part-two.aspx).

Comment: great link, that's your answer

Comment: Thanks SLaks! I discovered it by chance btw and got a birt surprised. Thanks for the link! I will accept your answer in 7 mins :)

Comment: If you read part two, don't forget to look at the date when it was posted or at least the update at the bottom of the article.

Comment: @svick: Did you really need to say that? :)

Comment: Brevity is not my strong suit.

Comment: @EricLippert: No; clarity and thoroughness are.